# Apply function take 100 time longer than a For loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm encountering a massive time difference between a `for` loop and an `apply` function.

I have a dataframe (alldat) that contain about 200k records with 73 columns I want to check what is the percent of NA in each column and return the result as a new DF for me to inspect. I have done it by 2 methods:

1) function with a `for` loop:

```
Nacheck = function(a){
    a <- as.data.frame(a)
    vecNA <- rep(NA, dim(a)[2])
    for (i in 1:dim(a)[2]){
        vecNA[i] <- sum(is.na(a[, i]))
        }
    rowss <- rep(nrow(a), length(vecNA))
    NA_PCT <- vecNA/rowss
    colna <- colnames(a)
    datacheck <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(colna, NA_PCT)))
    return(datacheck)
}
datacheck1 = Nacheck(alldat)
```

2) `apply` function by column:

```
datacheck <- as.data.frame(apply(alldat,2,function (x) round(sum(is.na(x))/dim(alldat)[1], digits = 2)))
```

the `apply` function take 4 sec and the for loop function takes less than 0.023 sec

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
datacheck <- as.data.frame(apply(alldat,2,function (x) round(sum(is.na(x))/dim(alldat)[1], digits = 2)))
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.takenapply <- end.time - start.time
time.takenapply
```

Time difference of 4.304 secs

`for` loop time :

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
datacheck = Nacheck(alldat)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Time difference of 0.02399993 secs

Am I doing something wrong?  Any idea what causes this time difference?

Comment: The `apply` function takes a matrix as an argument. Internal conversion of the input data to matrix may cause this time difference. Also I'd use `lapply` instead since you perform calculations over columns.

Comment: or `apply(df,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`

Comment: Not the cause of this, but why don't use `nrow(a)`,`ncol(a)` instead of `dim(a)[1]`,`dim(a)[2]` ?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Maybe try `colMeans(is.na(alldat))`

Comment: Natrave Drova and Jarko Dubbeldam you are correct, i used it with lapply and it fixed the time difference.   digEmAll -not particular reason (i'm new to r) thanks everyone for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dateframes are internally very similar to lists, with each column being a separate entry in the list. You can see this by using the `$` operator. This allows you to specify a column, similar to specifying a named entry in a list.

When you do `apply`, as Natrave Drova already mentioned in the comments, you are implicitly converting your entiry dataframe into a matrix. If your dataframe then has different datatypes, like columns of numerics and columns of characters, it coerces all values into a common type (usually character). If your dataframe is big (and 200k * 73 values to be coerces counts as big) this can be a very costly operation.

So if you want to compare the `*apply` functions with for-loops properly, you should try it with `lapply` instead.